# System.Diagnostics.Process.Kill doesn't work properly. C#

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, backgroundworker, system.diagnostics

I have `WinForm (.NET 4.5 C#)` application where I have `BackgroundWorker` from which i start new `Process` using code below.

```
    void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        BackgroundWorker bw = sender as BackgroundWorker;

        string fileName_ = e.Argument.ToString();

        Process myProcess = new Process();
        int exitCode = 0;

        try
        {
            if (!File.Exists(fileName_))
            {
                throw new FileNotFoundException("Failed to locate " + fileName_);

            }


            #region Start Info:
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(fileName_);
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;

            myProcess.StartInfo = startInfo; 
            #endregion

            myProcess.Start();
            StreamReader myStreamReader = myProcess.StandardOutput;

            while (!myProcess.HasExited)
            {
                myProcess.Refresh();
                string output = myStreamReader.ReadLine();
                bw.ReportProgress(0, output);

                if (bw.CancellationPending)
                {
                    myStreamReader.ReadToEnd();
                    myStreamReader.Close();

                    myProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();
                    myProcess.StandardError.Close();
                    myProcess.Kill();
                    break;

                }

            }


            //myProcess.WaitForExit();


            bw.ReportProgress(0, string.Format("Process {0}  exit code: {1}", fileName_, myProcess.ExitCode));

            exitCode = myProcess.ExitCode;
            if (exitCode != 0 && !bw.CancellationPending)
            {
                string error = myProcess.StandardError.ReadToEnd();


                myProcess.Close();
                myProcess = null;

                bw.ReportProgress(0, "Process Failed with message:" + Environment.NewLine + error);
            }

            myProcess.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {                

            Console.WriteLine(ex);

        }
        finally
        {
            myProcess.Dispose();
            myProcess = null;

        }

        e.Result = exitCode;
    }
```

This part works fine, but once I try to use `myProcess.Kill()`; background worker stops and everything ok, but I can see that my process is still running from Task Manager, even if I close my application I can still see in Task Manager that my process is running.

My question is, how to properly kill the process?

I hope I described my problem clearly, if not feel free to let me know if you need more information.

Any help would be appreciated.

//--------------Update Dec. 8th 2014 ---------------------//

@RogerN I removed Process.WaitForExit() and added myStreamReader.ReadToEnd() same issue process still alive even after application is closed.

@phillip This is console application (stand alone *.exe) that I call from my WinForm.

@Peter Duniho yes I am sure that it's the same process in Task Manager. Removing WaitForExit() didn't solve anything, BW in fact completed fine without any issue.

@L.B What alternative you would suggest?

Comment: what type of process is it?  if it is a service then you different answers than if it a stand-alone exe.

Comment: Are you sure that the process you see in Task Manager is the one you started? Your BW code calls `WaitForExit()` on the process it started and then killed, yet you claim that the BW does in fact complete. So there's a bit of a contradiction in the code vs what you're saying happens.

Comment: Are you running the program as administrator?

Comment: Hint: if you find yourself writing a code with busy waiting like `while (!myProcess.HasExited)` ,  `while (someTask.IsAlive)` or `while (someSource.DataAvailable)` be sure you are on the wrong track.

Answer (score 3):

Deadlock can occur because you are calling Process.WaitForExit() before reading the entire output stream.  Since you've redirected the output stream you must read all data from the associated stream before the process can exit normally.

Comment: This is normal console executable, I removed Process.WaitForExit() still the same problem. Yes I am sure that it's the same process in my task manager.

I tried to run as administrator and regular user same issue. 

What do you purpose to use instead of while loop?

Comment: Since you're redirecting both standard output and also the standard error stream, you'll need to make sure that you read to the end of both streams before the process can exit.  In your while loop above you are only reading from the standard output, not the standard error stream, so the process might never exit normally.

Comment: I updated while loop (see code on my first post), same issue process is still alive after closing application. There should be something else is wrong. Maybe I am setting ProcessStartInfo incorrectly?

Comment: Ok, I think I figured it out, it's something with this particular *.exe file, not sure exactly what but I tried to use different console *.exe and it works fine. Exit once I click cancel. 
Not sure what to do next, since I do need to run that particular console application. 
If anyone has hints or advice I would appreciate.

Comment: It's possible that myStreamReader.ReadLine() is blocking execution